# Setting Text Direction in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, hebrew

I am developing an addon for Docs, and need to set some Hebrew text right-to-left. I tried using the  [setLeftRight function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#setLeftToRight(Boolean)) with both 'true' and 'false', but none would set the text the right way. 

How can I set the text direction to RTL?

Edit: Sample code:

```
Code: var cells = [ ["EnglishTitle", "HebrewTitle"], ["Text", ""] ]; 
var tableStyle = {}; 
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = DocumentApp.FontFamily.TIMES_NEW_ROMAN;
tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12; 
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
doc.appendTable(cells).setAttributes(tableStyle).getCell(1,1).insertParagraph(0, "HebrewText").setLeftToRight(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works to set the text right to left:

```
function setRightToLeft() {
 var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
 var body = doc.getBody();
 var par = body.getParagraphs();
 par[0].setLeftToRight(false);
}
```

Note: You need to specify the specific paragraph that you want set right to left, or loop through all paragraphs to set them all that way.

**Edit:**

As you've mentioned below, there appears to be an issue with the escape character '\n' mucking up the right to left text. I've documented the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4578&thanks=4578&ts=1417341273) for review by Google, and hopefully they'll pick it up, but you'll need to star it to see if it gains any traction.

A workaround here is not use the escape character in the the '.insertParagraph()' method. Instead, use that only to insert the paragraph, then use the '.appendText()' method to add the text. For example, this works correctly for everything added in the '.appendText()' method:

```
function table(){
  Code: var cells = [ ["EnglishTitle", "HebrewTitle"], ["Text", ""] ]; 
  var tableStyle = {}; 
  tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = DocumentApp.FontFamily.TIMES_NEW_ROMAN;
  tableStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12; 
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  doc.appendTable(cells).setAttributes(tableStyle).getCell(1,1).insertParagraph(0, "Top line not moved. \nText Should Be Right to left, but it's not, \nThis text is correctly on the right.").setLeftToRight(false).appendText('\nThis is the appended text,\ncorrectly set right to left.');
}
```

Comment: For me Hebrew works, but for some reason, the Hebrew I am pulling with the UrlFetchApp isn't working. The full code is at [Github](https://github.com/shman/SefariaAddOn-Google). When the code is in the script editor and you have given it authorization, go to the doc, open the tab "Sefaria Library" and put in "Genesis 1" when prompted. Then you will see the error. @HDCerberus

Comment: I see the error, but something in the remainder of your code must be resetting the style. I'd recommend stripping the code down to the bare minimum to reproduce the error in order to find a solution, as the '.setLeftToRight' function is working correctly on it's own.

Comment: The culprit, @HDCerberus, is the newline character \n that is put in after every hebrew string posted to the doc. It is screwing with the text direction, somehow.

Comment: Interesting. I've appended more information to my answer which includes a workaround that should resolve your issue.