# Is there a way to make a table right-to-left in a document using Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, right-to-left, google-workspace

I want to know whether one can do any of the following in a Google document using Google Apps Script:

1. Create a right-to-left table
2. Modify a table's direction (from RTL to LTR, or vice versa)
3. Obtain a given table's direction

Google Apps Scripts provides an interface to the directionality of the `Paragraph` class: it has a `setLeftToRight()` method, as well as the `LEFT_TO_RIGHT` attribute. However, there are no equivalents to `TableCell`, `TableRow` or `Table`. Also, attempting to add a table after a right-to-left directed paragraph produces a left-to-right directed table.

In contrast, using the graphical interface to Google docs, when creating a table while the cursor is inside a right-to-left table, a right-to-left table is produced. Also, setting the direction inside any cell, changes the direction both of that cell and the entire table (though other cells remain with their original directionality).

I found no workaround to this issue and would appreciate some ideas. Meanwhile, I have [filed an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62505789) with the Google product team. The following sample code is also part of the submitted issue, but is given here so that it may be accessed without a Google account:

```
// run the following function on a document.
// it will append several paragraphs to the document, demonstrating the issue.
function tableDirectionIssueExample() {
  var rtlAttrs = {};
  rtlAttrs[DocumentApp.Attribute.LEFT_TO_RIGHT] = false;
  var ltrAttrs = {};
  ltrAttrs[DocumentApp.Attribute.LEFT_TO_RIGHT] = true;

  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var par;

  par = body.appendParagraph("The next table is in a left-to-right direction:");
  par.setAttributes(ltrAttrs);
  var tableLtr = body.appendTable([["a","b"],["c","d"]]);

  par = body.appendParagraph("The next table should be in a right-to-left direction, as that is what the graphical interface does, but it isn't:");
  par.setAttributes(rtlAttrs);
  var tableRtl = body.appendTable([["a","b"],["c","d"]]);

  body.appendParagraph("Getting the left-to-right attribute of a table results in the value: " + tableLtr.getAttributes()[DocumentApp.Attribute.LEFT_TO_RIGHT]);
  body.appendParagraph("The following table will be created with a default direction, and then we'll attempt setting the left-to-right property to false, but to no avail...");
  var tableExplicitRtl = body.appendTable([["a","b"],["c","d"]]);
  tableExplicitRtl.setAttributes(rtlAttrs);
  tableExplicitRtl.getRow(0).setAttributes(rtlAttrs);
  tableExplicitRtl.getRow(0).getCell(0).setAttributes(rtlAttrs);
  tableExplicitRtl.getRow(0).getCell(0).getChild(0).setAttributes(rtlAttrs); 
  body.appendParagraph("You'll notice the only thing that was succesful is setting the paragraph of the first cell as right-to-left, but that didn't affect the rest of the table. That is again unlike the graphical interface, where hitting a direction button on any cell changes the directionality of the entire table.");

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Text Direction in Google Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180697/setting-text-direction-in-google-scripts)